# Events in cpp/opengl

Tags: c++, events, opengl

I would like to create infrastructure to handle events for my opengl project.
It should be similar to what wpf has - 3 types of events - direct, tunneling, bubbling.
I then want to handle events such as mouse up, down, move etc.
How should i approach this problem? Is there any library to handle this.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [OpenGL Utility Toolkit](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) (GLUT) provides precisely this - you set up a bunch of event handlers for things like keyboard input, mouse input, redrawing the display, and window resizing, call the `glutMainLoop()` function, and you're good to go.